# odata.maxpagesize header not working in Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the [Graph Explorer](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/graph-explorer) to try out some requests (`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events`), but my data was too big to easily parse. So I tried to use the `Prefer: odata.maxpagesize=3` header as documented, but the response still returned the full list of events. I tried both with `v1.0` and `beta`.

Checking the Network console in Chrome, the `Prefer: odata.maxpagesize=3` is included in the request headers, but `Preference-Applied` is missing from the response headers.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this, it definitely works:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$top=3&$skip=3
```

> Paging is achieved by using the $top parameter to specify a page size
>   and the $skip parameter as a multiple of the page size. By
>   incrementing the $skip parameter value by the page size you can
>   request the next page in the set of results.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#page-results

Comment: Specifying `Prefer: odata.track-changes,odata.maxpagesize=3` doesn't seem to work properly in the Graph Explorer. It still returns the full event list, and checking the Network logs, the `odata.maxpagesize=3` value is missing from the request headers.

Comment: Per [spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part1-protocol-complete.html#_Toc406398233), if you aren't seeing the Preference-Applied response header, it will mean one of two things: either the service doesn't support the preference, or the service has not implemented (the MAY statement in Odata spec) the Preference-Applied response header. If I recall correctly (~60% confidence), if it is supported, Graph services return the Preference-Applied response header.